# Running a new iteration for each column of a dataset in ArcGIS

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

I'm pretty new to Modelbuilding, having just been turned onto it about a week ago on here. So my problem is, I currently have a dataset of habitats that change through time (from Immature to Mature, or remaining Mature, etc). I would like to create a shapefile for each habitat type for each year. Currently I am able to do this by hand, running a Feature Selection iteration on each field and running the "feature class to feature class" tool to export it as a shapefile. What I was wondering was, is there any way to automate this process across a number of different columns? So, run the iteration and shapefile export for the 1995 field, 1996 field, 1997 field, etc, etc. I'm trying my best right now to sort it out in Python, but today was day 1 of learning and was hoping that there was another method out there that someone may be able to point me in the right direction of.

Hopefully this makes sense, if you need any more info, please let me know.

Thanks very much in advance.

**EDIT** - Example data - The cut off for going from young (or Disturbance) to a mature forest is 40 years. So the field "Year" is the year the forest began growing (or year since it was removed) and under each year is the forest class for that year.

```
FID    Year    1995           1996          1997         1998
0      1992  Disturbance  Disturbance  Disturbance  Disturbance
1      1854  Black Spruce Black Spruce Black Spruce Black Spruce
2      1960  Disturbance  Disturbance  Disturbance  Disturbance
3      1875  Deciduous    Deciduous    Deciduous    Deciduous
4      1956  Disturbance  Disturbance  Jack Pine    Jack Pine
5      1957  Disturbance  Disturbance  Disturbance  Lowland Conifer
```

And this is the model I am currently using, I would like this to be re-run across all of my year fields (columns)

[image]

Comment: Can you explain a little more about how your data is structured? A few rows of sample data (input and output) would be useful.

Comment: And what is the desired output given the sample input?

Comment: The desired output from the model I gave would be a shapefile for each unique habitat classification (one for Deciduous, one for Disturbance, one for Lowland Conifer, etc) for the year 2008. It would go down the entire row, subset each polygon that is associated with that classification, and create a new shapefile with all of the occurrences of that classification. So what I hope to do is make it so that the model would run through the field "2008", but would then run through the field "2009","2010",etc. Repeating for each year that I have. A new shapefile for each habitat class for each year

Comment: I may have sorted it out on my own, although its not very elegant. But its essentially the same model as I posted above, but copying the "feature class to feature class" tool and in the equation bar saying "Year"=%Value% and changing "Year" to equal the Field that I want a new shapefile for. Its running through now, but is taking a while as the dataset is huge. If anyone know a better way to do this, please let me know. And if not, I'll check in the morning to see if it worked and if so I'll answer my own question. Thanks

Comment: Since each row already has the attributes for each year wouldn't it be redundant to do what you're asking? What is the use case? What good are a bunch of shapefiles with 1 feature each, when you could just query the information you are after from the main feature class/shapefile? You could create layers for each year and symbolize by classification in various ways if you were so inclined.

Comment: Also when I asked what the desired output was, I meant for you to post the attribute tables of the desired outputs, similar to how you posted a sample attribute table of the input.

Comment: Oh right, hah, makes more sense. The output would essentially be the exact same as the input but with just a single field (year) and only a single class in each. Its so that I can run the Euclidean distance raster creation tool on the resultant class and year specific shapefiles. Trying to determine animal location distances from each habitat type in over a span of about 15 years. The shapefiles are just a middle step that I don't know how to avoid/want to keep them in case I have to go back for something...

Comment: The input to the [Euclidean Distance](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000001p000000) tool is either a raster or a feature layer. Instead of creating a bunch of intermediate shapefiles you could create a feature layer with [Make Feature Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000006p000000) and pass that into the Euclidean Distance tool.